# ASP.NET MVC External Custom Login Provider using OAUTH 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, owin

i'm working in a new project with ASP.NET MVC 5 and we want to authenticate all users with a custom identity server. We use OWIN and OAuth 2.0 code authorization flow. Right now we have a issue with the authentication, the first time we try to authenticate we can do it, but the second one we can not. The only way it authenticate again is recycling the app pool inside iis.

This is how we configure authentication middleware

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cookieExpirationTime),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseCustomAuthentication(
            "Client_id",
            "Client_secret"
            );
    }
```

In our AccountController, the first line of the method **ExternalLoginCallback** always return null, after recycle the app pool it return a loginInfo and we can logged in.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                 ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { UserName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName });
        }
    }
```

We tested our custom middleware with the default visual studio web app template and it worked. Anyone knows what is happening?

**Note:** We are using Ninject as our DI container.

Comment: Do not try to implement your own solution, try this instead http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/

Comment: Hello, did you decided your task?